What is wrong with this proof about index of vector fields on the sphere
I wonder what is wrong with the proof below. I have a counterexample $G=(1-x^2,-xy,-xz)$ which vanishes only at $(\pm 1, 0,0)$ and the index of each of these points are +1. Thus the argument below does not work. Can someone hint which part of the argument is wrong. Can the argument work under some additional assumptions on the vector field $G$?

Let $\mathbb{G}$ be a continuous vector field on $\mathbb{S}^2$ such that $\mathbb{G}(x) = \mathbb{G}(-x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{S}^2$. If $\mathbb{G}$ vanishes at $x^*, -x^* \in \mathbb{S}^2$ then we must have
\begin{equation}\label{index}
\operatorname{Ind}_{x^*} \mathbb{G} + \operatorname{Ind}_{-x^*} \mathbb{G} = 0.
\end{equation}
Let $\Gamma$ be a small circle on $\mathbb{S}^2$ centered at $x^*$. Define
$$\bar{\Gamma} = \{-x \in \mathbb{S}^2: x \in \Gamma\}.$$
Now fix a point $x_0 \in \Gamma$. Parametrize the circle $\Gamma$ with $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, such that the parametrization is in a counterclockwise orientation when viewed from the point $x^*$, say $\gamma: [0,2\pi] \to \Gamma$ with $\gamma(0) = x_0$. This parametrization also provides a parametrization for $\bar{\Gamma}$ as follows: $\bar{\gamma}: [0,2\pi] \to \bar{\Gamma}$
$$\bar{\gamma}(\theta) = -\gamma(\theta).$$
Now notice that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{G}(\bar{\gamma}(\theta)) = \mathbb{G}(\gamma(\theta)), \quad \theta \in [0,2\pi],
\end{equation}
but $\bar{\Gamma}$ is parametrized in a clockwise direction when viewed from the point $-x^*$. Hence, $\operatorname{Ind}_{-x^*} \mathbb{G} = -\operatorname{Ind}_{x^*} \mathbb{G}$, and the proof is complete.


$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$The equation $\mathbb{G}(\bar{\gamma}(\theta)) = \mathbb{G}(\gamma(\theta))$ is misleading: It equates values of a vector field at two different points. It leads us to mentally identify tangent spaces of the ambient Cartesian space by translation. But that leads to the second, explanatory observation:
Let $p$ be a point of $S^{n} \subset \Reals^{n+1}$. The antipodal map of $\Reals^{n+1}$ induces a map on $S^{n}$, which induces an "antipodal map" from $T_{p}S^{n}$ to $T_{-p}S^{n}$. This map is orientation reversing as a map of tangent spaces to the sphere if $n$ is even (and orientation preserving if $n$ is odd). Geometrically, imagine parallel transporting $T_{p}S^{n}$ to $T_{-p}S^{n}$ along an arc of great circle (which is "orientation-preserving relative to the sphere") and comparing the result with ambient parallel translation.
On the $2$-sphere, as shown, the direction tangent to the great circle is "antipoded" while the direction normal to the great circle moves by ambient translation. In words, ambiently translating $T_{p}S^{2}$ to $T_{-p}S^{2}$ reverses orientation. This means the proposed argument mis-signs the index at $-p$.


Thank you so much Andrew. Would it be safe to say that the index of $G$ at such antipodal points will always be equal?

Carefully formulating and proving a statement of that type (particularly, what hypotheses are needed on the vector field?) is a good exercise!

I thought your argument combined with mine already implies that the index of such antipodal zeros are equal (under the same assumption: $\mathbb{G}(x)=\mathbb{G}(-x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{S}^2)$. Am I wrong? Do we need additional assumptions to guarantee this?

Briefly: (i) yes, continuity and oddness of $\mathbb{G}$ as a function on Cartesian space imply "equality of index at antipodal points" ... so long as the restriction to the unit sphere is a tangent vector field with isolated zeros. My comment may be understood as expressing that as a mathematician I get nervous when (ii) hypotheses become separated from conclusions and (iii) "safe to say" is used to assert the conclusion of a theorem. ;)

Thank you. Did you mean evenness of $\mathbb{G}$ and not oddness? $\mathbb{G}$ is assumed to be even here.

You're right, I did mean evenness. (IIRC, however, the claim is true as stated: On a surface, multiplying a vector field pointwise by $-1$ preserves the index of an isolated zero. :)

Note that homotopy type theory prevents such "type errors" by giving $\mathbb{G}$ the dependent function type $(p : S^n) \to T_p S^n$, so you cannot even state $\mathbb{G}(x) = \mathbb{G}(-x)$ without first saying how $x$ and $-x$ are identified, i.e. giving a path around the sphere. Then the meaning of that equation is that transporting $\mathbb{G}(x)$ along that path yields $\mathbb{G}(-x)$.
